# Transistors: How does the gate work?

Tags: electrochemistry

Two questions:

First, how does the gate provide a positive charge by running a current through it? I really just don't see how this positive charge could be achieved, unless you had some sort of battery in the gate itself and attached a wire to donate some of the electrons flowing through to the cathode of some other battery. Is it possible to get electrons out of the gate by some other means?

Comment: perhaps this should be asked on Physics.SE

Comment: Is there a significant $I_{GD}$ in FETs? In contrast to BJTs, the former aren't current-, but voltage-controlled. A conducting channel between source and drain is typically induced by applying a (positive) voltage between gate and source.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Applying a positive voltage on the gate means that electrons are moving into the gate, right? But wouldn't that make the gate more negative?

Comment: Why wouldn't the electrons move to the positive voltage source? Instead of Physics SE I might suggest Electrical Engineering.  But, you seem to have a number of concepts mixed up with each other, so a little more thought should be placed before re-asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

The gate of a FET works much like the grid of a radio tube (valve). The gate is insulated from source and drain; the only current flow (if the insulator were perfect) is to charge the intrinsic gate capacitance. Even a MOSFET has *some* leakage, but it's pico- or femtoamperes. See [this discussion](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31594/mosfet-when-can-we-not-assume-that-the-gate-current-is-0) on capacitance and leakage.

Answer (score 1):

It is really not charge injection, but charge separation. When a potential is applied to the gate with respect to the SD, the charges in the gate dielectric separate. This separation creates a layer of positive or negative charges just next to the SD channel.

In ideal cases there is no current through the gate.